# Bootstrap getting navbar to the right side

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hi guys so i got my background image ready and sorted on my site, i have my logo on the left side and i am trying to get my navbar on the same line as the logo but on the ride side of the screen ,

Example of a site: [Site](http://www.iplay.global/)

So far i have :

HTML:

```
<div class="parallax">
    <div class ="logo">
        <img src="Images/logo1.fw.png">
    </div> 

 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
   .parallax {
        background-image: url("../Images/back1.jpg");
        min-height: 1000px;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .parallax1 {
        min-height: 1000px;
    }

    .logo {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    .navbar-default {
        background-color: transparent;
        border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        border-right: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
        color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: Newest one , but all fixed now x

Comment: Well you should avoid custom css when possible - use the library classes. So bootstrap 4? Bootstrap 3 is the latest public release, but a lot of people already upgraded to bootstrap 4, which is in alpha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to float the navbar next to the logo:

```
.logo {
  float: left;
}

.navbar {
  float: right;
}
```

I've created a JSFiddle demonstrating this **[here](https://jsfiddle.net/mkL9d1za/)**, replacing your relative images with some placeholders.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: No problem! Glad to hear this solution appears to have helped you. Once you've confirmed this solution solves your problem, please don't forget to mark the solution as correct by clicking on the grey check below the vote buttons -- this removes it from the 'Unanswered Questions' queue, and awards reputation to both the question asker and question answerer. Of course, in saying that, you are under no obligation to mark my answer (or any other answer) as correct, though it does help to keep things on StackOverflow flowing smoothly :)

Comment: Ah ye of course, i just need to wait 5 mins :) and then of course i will x

Answer (score 0):

Using bootstrap 4, you should utilize the helper classes. You can make the element `display: flex; justify-content: space-between` with `.d-flex` and `.justify-content-between`. If you want to vertically center them, you can use `.align-items-center`

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>
body {
  background: black;
}

.parallax {
  background-image: url("../Images/back1.jpg");
  min-height: 1000px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
}

.parallax1 {
  min-height: 1000px;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 40px;
}

.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-right: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
</style>
<div class="parallax">
  <header class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="Images/logo1.fw.png">
  </div>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
              <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!--/.container-fluid -->
  </nav>
  </header>
</div>
```

Or if you're on bootstrap 3, use the `.pull-left` and `.pull-right` classes to float the logo left and nav right.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style>
  body {
    background: black;
  }
  
  .parallax {
    background-image: url("../Images/back1.jpg");
    min-height: 1000px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .parallax1 {
    min-height: 1000px;
  }
  
  .logo {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  
  .navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-top: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-left: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-right: 0px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
  
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #ffffff;
  }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="parallax">
      <div class="logo pull-left">
        <img src="Images/logo1.fw.png">
      </div>

      <nav class="navbar navbar-default pull-right">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RobotMan you're welcome. Gave you a solution with bootstrap 3 and 4. You should generally avoid using custom CSS when you can use the library classes that do the same thing instead.